# Elasticsearch vs Kafka: Putting intelligence in producers

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, distributed-system

Elasticsearch and Kafka are two examples of distributed systems but both take different approaches towards having intelligence in data producers - in ES producers of data have no say on where the data will be stored. They simply ask the cluster to store the data. In Kafka the producer knows the internal state of the cluster (it knows which nodes the partitions of a topic are on) and is able to tell the cluster to store the data on a particular partition.

Clearly Kafka and ES are built for different use cases but I'm struggling to connect those use cases to this design decision - why does Kafka allow producers to determine where to store data but ES doesn't?

Answer (score 8):

> They simply ask the cluster to store the data

That's not true. In ES you can leverage [`routing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-routing) in order to decide in which shard your document will end up. Pretty much the same concept as deciding on which Kafka topic partition your message will be stored.

Kafka and ES are clearly built for different use cases. The former is a distributed commit log and the latter is a search and analytics engine. Different products, different use cases.

Even though they are different, they are complimentary and can work pretty well "together" [via Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html), where Kafka can play the role of an input buffer to Elasticsearch

Comment: In 2020, this seems less true. Both can be used for most functions, all alone by themselves.